# Rest-MongoDB error while adding data using post method using angular2

Tags: java, mongodb, angular, jersey

I am using angular2,Rest and mongodb for my project .I am trying to post data to the server using post method.Now the problem is that i am able to post the data to the server using Postman .The data is getting added to the database as well.But when i try to add data  from the front end,i am getting the response as okay from the server but the data is not getting added to the database.I don't understand why because if the data is getting added using postman ,i don't understand why is it not getting added from the front end

Following are my codes

Angular Post method

```
const url:string="http://localhost:8080/JarvisBackend/Jarvis/addLeave";
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(data),options).map(
  res=>{
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  }
```

Rest Service

```
@POST
    @Path("/addLeave")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getUserById(LeaveApplyBean l) {
        System.out.println(l.getNum());
        int k = new leaveApplyDao().applyLeave(l);
        return "{}";
    }
```

DAO

```
public class leaveApplyDao {
    public int applyLeave(LeaveApplyBean lb) {
        try {


            MongoDatabase md = new MongoConnector().getConnection();
            Document details = new        FindApproverDao().finDetails(lb.getNum(), md);

            Document task = new Document();

            task.append("start_date", lb.getStartDate());
            task.append("end_date", lb.getEndDate());
            task.append("desciption", lb.getDescription());

            Document obj = new Document();
            obj.append("type", "Leave");
            obj.append("creator", lb.getNum());


            obj.append("approver", details.get("manager"));
            obj.append("cftid", details.get("cftid"));

            obj.append("status", "pending");

            obj.append("task", task);

            MongoCollection mc = md.getCollection("tasks");

            mc.insertOne(obj);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
  }
```

Helper Dao

```
public class FindApproverDao {

    public Document finDetails(String num,MongoDatabase md)
    {

        ArrayList list =null;
        FindIterable cursor = null;
        Document d=null;
        MongoCollection mc;
        try {
            BasicDBObject criteria =new BasicDBObject();
            criteria.append("num",num);

            mc = md.getCollection("employee");
             d = (Document) mc
                        .find(new BasicDBObject("num", num))
                         .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("manager","cftid"), Projections.excludeId())).first();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println(d.get("manager"));
        return d;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println(new FindApproverDao().finDetails("AHSH", new MongoConnector().getConnection()).get("cftid"));
    }


}
```

and by bean class

```
public class LeaveApplyBean {

    private String num;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private String description;

    public String getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setNum(String num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

and the response from the server in console

> Response {_body: "{}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers…}

Please help.I am stuck.Any help would be appreciated